# How to assign DOM created objects unique identifiers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, for-loop

This is my first question, so apologies if it's not specific enough or critical details are lacking.

I'm learning JS through tutorials and applying it to building what equates to a deck builder.

A bunch of cards show up, you choose one and it's added to the deck.
Those cards are turned into objects and added to an array that represents the cards chosen to be in the deck

**My issue arrises when multiple of the same cards are put into a deck, and you want to remove just one of them.** I cannot target just the one because all my comparison operators pick up both instances.

Here is my repo on Github in case it wasn't explained well enough: 
https://github.com/caldwell619/armada-fleet/tree/data-attr

Specifically, here are the snippets I'm struggling with:

Removal of a ship from the array `chosenFleet.ships`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < chosenFleet.ships.length; i++) {
    if ($(this).data("name") === chosenFleet.ships[i].name) {
        chosenFleet.ships.splice(i, 1);
```

I tried applying a unique identifier to all of the objects, but since my function is based off rewritting the HTML,

```
 pickedShips.innerHTML = "";
            for (let ship of chosenFleet.ships) {
                // div creation
                const shipSel = shipSelect(ship);
                pickedShips.appendChild(shipSel);
```

All of the unique identifiers end up being the same because every time the event listener fires, HTML elements are rewritten based on the current state of the array `ships`.

Function that creates the HTML based on which ship is selected:

```
const shipSelect = (ship) => {
const selectedShipContainer = document.createElement("div");
const shipImgContainer = document.createElement("div");
const shipNameContainer = document.createElement("div");
const shipImg = document.createElement("img");
const shipName = document.createElement("p");
const upgradeBar = document.createElement("div");
const deleteElement = document.createElement("span");
shipImgContainer.className = "span-4-of-12 ship-img";
shipImgContainer.appendChild(shipImg);
shipImg.src = "images/cards/ship/empire/" + ship.imageName;
selectedShipContainer.appendChild(shipImgContainer);
selectedShipContainer.className = "selected-ship-container";
upgradeBar.setAttribute("data-name", ship.name);
//add selected ship to new div
shipNameContainer.className = "span-7-of-12 ship-name";
shipNameContainer.appendChild(shipName);
shipNameContainer.appendChild(deleteElement);
deleteElement.className = "delete ion-trash-a";
deleteElement.setAttribute("data-name", ship.name);
deleteElement.setAttribute("data-points", ship.points);
//using data to make DOM manipulation
selectedShipContainer.setAttribute("data-name", ship.name);

shipName.innerHTML = ship.name;
selectedShipContainer.appendChild(shipNameContainer);
upgradeBar.className = "upgrade-bar";
selectedShipContainer.appendChild(upgradeBar);
const specificUpgrades = Object.keys(ship.upgrades);
for (let up of specificUpgrades) {
    const butt = upgradeButtonMake(up);
    upgradeBar.appendChild(butt);
}
pickedShips.appendChild(selectedShipContainer);
// return throwaway;
return selectedShipContainer;
```

};

Again, if this is too long / too short / etc, my apologies. Noob here.

Comment: The best solution here is to not store data in the DOM. The DOM is a display layer, you should store your state in an in-memory object, and update the DOM to reflect mutations to your state

Answer (score 2):

You may create more specific sheep identity
e.g something like

```
deleteElement.setAttribute("data-id", ship.name + ship.type);
```

**type** is whatever attribute that better specifies your ship.

and then compare on this attr

```
if ($(this).data("id") === chosenFleet.ships[i].name + chosenFleet.ships[i].type) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a global object like

```
(function (global) {
  global.getUniq = getUniq;
  var id = 0;

  function getUniq() {
    return ++id;
  }
})(window);
```

It's a singleton and each time you call getUniq you get a unique identifier no matter how many clients use it.

Comment: "Create a global object--" a lot of people just flipped their tables and wrecked their laptops.